# HyperLogLog implementation with Spark batch + Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, hyperloglog

I am looking to implement HyperLogLog algorithm to count distinct users for different audience segments (or filters). I user Cassandra + Spark batch. Wondering if Cassandra provides any support for HyperLogLog type.

I could not find any plugin or anything related except http://vilkeliskis.com/blog/2013/12/28/hacking_cassandra.html which is a great attempt but unfinished.

Thanks for any possible hints!

Answer (score 1):

Spark 2.0 has a [native implementation of HyperLogLog++](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/19/approximate-algorithms-in-apache-spark-hyperloglog-and-quantiles.html).